# Mysterious extra text in style check

Tags: c, cs50

I am working on CS50's Runoff problem in Problem Set 3, and the program is working when I run it. When I run the check program, however, it notes one particular function as being wrong entirely despite it working when I run the program manually. When I run the style check program to make sure there is no excess whitespace, etc; the results show extra text where there is none in the program.

[image: A screenshot of the issue]

[image: A screenshot of the check error]

In both of the screenshots I have the function returning the error in the top window.

Any ideas what is causing the mystery text, or the 4 errors? If it s more helpful, I can paste the entirety of the code here.

Thank you!

Comment: Please do not post code and text logs as images or links to images - [reasoning](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question). Copy it as formatted text into the question.

Comment: @kaylum Come on, the problem they're having is related to text they can't copy and paste.

Comment: @Barmar Good point. Though the second screenshot and related question  is not related to styling (AFAICS).

Comment: Delete those two lines and type them again. The incorrect output is likely a different issue in the logic of the program.

Comment: Wait, wait, there's "style check" code that instead of just removing the dangling whitespace, instead *complains* about it?! Oh boy. That's stupid in the extreme. Computers can do that stuff, they don't need to whine about it first :(

Comment: The red and green data in the second screenshot is unreadable for me. I recommend using a tool like `od` to show exactly what the ascii code of the program text is.

Comment: What "style check program" is that?

Comment: @WeatherVane Ut seems to be part of CS50 IDE.

Comment: Doesn't "more than half the votes" depend on the number of _voters_, not the number of candidates?

Comment: [Style50](https://cs50.readthedocs.io/style50/) Likely you have a line with a `'\r'` carriage-return in it.

Answer (score 1):

Do not be distracted by style50. Any style issues should never change the results of the program. The program is failing check50 because of functional deficiencies. The spec for print_winner says:

> If any candidate has more than half of the vote, their name should be printed to `stdout` and the function should return `true`.

"More than half the vote" depends on the number of *voters* not the number of candidates. Try an election with 3 candidates a, b, c with 7 voters who vote b,b,b,b,a,a,c. Who wins? (b). What result does program return?

Deal with style issues after program passes check50 and before submit50. (But it's good practice to double check check50 results after cleaning up style, lest a bug creep in :)